# 502 and 504 error after application starts

Tags: docker, nginx

When running my application using docker, nginx, the application would start then time out and give me 504 or 502 errors. Upon restarting after shutting down, doing a **docker system prune** restarting my docker server in windows the application would start and then stop again. How do I resolve these errors?

Comment: Can you provide more information about the issue, because it's too broad?

Comment: In my experience if error 502 comes with nginx than the root path from where you are serving the files is missing(there can be many issues other than this but i found this more relevant). you should double check the root path of nginx.

Answer (score 0):

For me it turns out it was a memory issue. I ended up increase the memory from 2G to 4G. That has resolved the issue. I did this in 2 steps:

1. increasing it in the HyperV because I am using windows:

   a. I had to open Hyper-V Manager, stopped the **MobyLinux VM** Added more 
     memory by right clicking it and going to settings, then memory.

   b. restarting the VM
2. Went into the Docker application via the whale clicked on advance and then increased the memory, thanks to the following directions:[Increase Docker Memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44533319/how-to-assign-more-memory-to-docker-container)

Then my application stopped crashing! I hope this helps someone else!