# docker build failed after pip installed requirements with exit code 137

Tags: docker, pip, docker-compose, dockerfile

I am starting a new django project and want to dockerize the project, on my ubuntu. when I run `docker-compose up --build` I got a strange Error. It seems that it has problem with pip install requirements.

I have tried to search for the meaning of "exit code 137", most say it is "out of memory" but it doesn't seem like that in my case.

Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.6
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install apt-transport-https
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir pipenv

RUN mkdir /my-django
WORKDIR /my-django
ADD requirements.txt /my-django/

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
```

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3'

services:
  db:
    image: postgres:11
    restart: unless-stopped
    volumes:
      - trkr-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    ports:
      - 11000:5432
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_DB='myDB'
      - POSTGRES_USER='myDB'
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD='myDB'

  web:
    build: .
    restart: on-failure
    container_name: my-django
    image: trkr_web:latest
    volumes:
      - .:/my-django
    env_file:
      - ./.env
    command: python manage.py migrate && python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    depends_on:
      - db

#sepcify volumes
volumes:
  my-data:
```

when I run `make up` (I have a Makefile with up: docker-compose up --build), I got the following error message:

```
......
Collecting Django==2.2.3 (from -r requirements.txt (line 1))
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/39/b0/2138c31bf13e17afc32277239da53e9dfcce27bac8cb68cf1c0123f1fdf5/Django-2.2.3-py3-none-any.whl (7.5MB)
Collecting django-environ==0.4.5 (from -r requirements.txt (line 2))
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/9f/32/76295a1a5d00bf556c495216581c6997e7fa5f533b2229e0a9d6cbaa95ae/django_environ-0.4.5-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting pipenv==2018.10.13 (from -r requirements.txt (line 3))
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/90/06/0008f53835495fbbf6e31ced9119b8f517e1271bdefcf0d04aaa9f28dbf4/pipenv-2018.10.13-py3-none-any.whl (5.2MB)
Collecting psycopg2-binary==2.7.5 (from -r requirements.txt (line 4))
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/3f/4e/b9a5cb7c7451029f67f93426cbb5f5bebedc3f9a8b0a470de7d0d7883602/psycopg2_binary-2.7.5-cp36-cp36m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (2.7MB)
Collecting pytz (from Django==2.2.3->-r requirements.txt (line 1))
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/3d/73/fe30c2daaaa0713420d0382b16fbb761409f532c56bdcc514bf7b6262bb6/pytz-2019.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (510kB)
Collecting sqlparse (from Django==2.2.3->-r requirements.txt (line 1))
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/ef/53/900f7d2a54557c6a37886585a91336520e5539e3ae2423ff1102daf4f3a7/sqlparse-0.3.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Requirement already satisfied: pip>=9.0.1 in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from pipenv==2018.10.13->-r requirements.txt (line 3)) (18.1)
Requirement already satisfied: virtualenv in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from pipenv==2018.10.13->-r requirements.txt (line 3)) (16.7.2)
Requirement already satisfied: certifi in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from pipenv==2018.10.13->-r requirements.txt (line 3)) (2019.6.16)
Requirement already satisfied: virtualenv-clone>=0.2.5 in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from pipenv==2018.10.13->-r requirements.txt (line 3)) (0.5.3)
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools>=36.2.1 in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from pipenv==2018.10.13->-r requirements.txt (line 3)) (40.6.2)
Installing collected packages: pytz, sqlparse, Django, django-environ, pipenv, psycopg2-binary
  Found existing installation: pipenv 2018.11.26
    Uninstalling pipenv-2018.11.26:
      Successfully uninstalled pipenv-2018.11.26
Successfully installed Django-2.2.3 django-environ-0.4.5 pipenv-2018.10.13 psycopg2-binary-2.7.5 pytz-2019.1 sqlparse-0.3.0
Killed
ERROR: Service 'web' failed to build: The command '/bin/sh -c pip install -r requirements.txt' returned a non-zero code: 137
Makefile:2: recipe for target 'up' failed
```

> This problem is solved by `RUN pip3 install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt`

Comment: What does `docker-compose logs db` say? Also - though it's probably not related - it looks like you're installing pipenv two times

Comment: I changed the pip to pip3 `RUN pip3 install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt` it worked

Comment: Your solution `--no-cache-dir` is a good answer: If you add it as an answer, I'll delete the community wiki answer and upvote yours :)

Answer (score 19):

I was getting the below error on my windows machine:

> Killed
> ERROR: Service 'kafka-asr' failed to build: The command '/bin/sh -c pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt' returned a non-zero code: 137

After increasing the docker memory the error got resolved.

- Right click on docker -> setting -> Advance

I increased the memory 2304 to 2816 and clicked on Apply.

[image]

Answer (score 7):

Adding the answer given at the end of the question:

> This problem is solved by `RUN pip3 install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt`

Comment: Used this solution and it worked!

Answer (score 3):

**Solution**

Allocate more RAM to Docker (as @PravinKumar said above).

Here are [screenshots](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68012385/968003) of the settings screen for various Docker versions.

**Reason**

That `code 137` error occurs on *Linux*/*OS X* and actually means `Fatal error signal "9"` ([explanation here](https://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/exitcodes.html)) that corresponds to `Out Of Memory` exception followed by SIGKILL signal killing the process.

**Useful links**

- Good [discussion on GitHub](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/21083)
- Official guideline from Docker: [Understand the risks of running out of memory](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/resource_constraints/#memory).

Answer (score 0):

For me, the error got resolved after increasing the storage size instead of RAM size. FYI.

I used to get the below error.

```
. . .
Killed
The command '/bin/sh -c pip install -r /tmp/requirements.txt' returned a non-zero code: 137
```

In Mac, if you are using the latest docker version, please do the below.

Docker => Preferences... => Docker Engine => change the experimental feature like below. Here I have mentioned as 30GB you can increase based on your need.

```
    {
      "experimental": false,
      "builder": {
        "gc": {
          "enabled": true,
          "defaultKeepStorage": "30GB"
        }
      },
      "features": {
        "buildkit": false
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I could not try [this solution](https://samwize.com/2016/05/19/docker-error-returned-a-non-zero-code-137/) because of user privileges on the server host I'm using.

I'm not sure why, but using this version of docker compose

```
mkdir -p ~/.docker/cli-plugins/
curl -SL https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/download/v2.3.3/docker-compose-linux-x86_64 -o ~/.docker/cli-plugins/docker-compose
chmod +x ~/.docker/cli-plugins/docker-compose
```

helped with this issue. Now instead of using

```
docker-compose up --build
```

I used (without the dash in between docker and compose)

```
docker compose up --build
```

The caveats I noticed down the line, when rebuilding my images, new containers were not recreated using `"docker compose up --build"`. I could now use `"docker-compose up --build"` without getting the `code 137 error` because the requirements where cached.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered a similar issue on Windows due to RAM limitations. Originally, I had set a maximum RAM usage for Docker in the .wslconfig file since I had only 8GB of RAM but it's not enough to create my image. after upgrading to 24GB and deleted the .wslconfig file located at c:\ Users\ [your_account]\ .wslconfig. This allowed Docker to use as much RAM as needed to create the image and it works!!

Answer (score -1):

This error is solved with following changes in the Dockerfile:

```
RUN pip install --upgrade pip; \
    pip install -r requirements.txt

COPY . /trkr-django
```

now the build is successful but I encountered a database connection error.