# Installing requirements.txt in Docker runs out of memory

Tags: python, docker, macos, pip

I want to install requirements.txt in my docker container, but I end up having this error:

```
....
1.261 Requirement already satisfied: pytest>=5.2 in /home/sailor/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from -r ros-nodes/requirements.txt (line 17)) (8.0.2)
1.262 Requirement already satisfied: pyyaml in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (from -r ros-nodes/requirements.txt (line 18)) (5.4.1)
1.294 Collecting types-PyYAML (from -r ros-nodes/requirements.txt (line 19))
1.321   Downloading types_PyYAML-6.0.12.12-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (1.4 kB)
1.357 Collecting PyQt5>=5.15.4 (from -r ros-nodes/requirements.txt (line 20))
1.379   Downloading PyQt5-5.15.10.tar.gz (3.2 MB)
1.654      ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 3.2/3.2 MB 12.1 MB/s eta 0:00:00
1.901   Installing build dependencies: started
3.584   Installing build dependencies: finished with status 'done'
3.585   Getting requirements to build wheel: started
3.653   Getting requirements to build wheel: finished with status 'done'
3.653   Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml): started
994.4 Killed
------
Dockerfile:59
--------------------
  57 |     # Install Pyrate and ROS Nodes requirements
  58 |     RUN pip install --upgrade pip && pip install ./pyrate
  59 | >>> RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r ros-nodes/requirements.txt
  60 |     
  61 |     # Install final dependencies via rosdep
--------------------
ERROR: failed to solve: process "/bin/sh -c pip install --no-cache-dir -r ros-nodes/requirements.txt" did not complete successfully: exit code: 137
```

I already tried adding the `--no-cache-dir` flag as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57291806/docker-build-failed-after-pip-installed-requirements-with-exit-code-137), but it does not solve the issue.

As you can see from the screenshot attached, I am giving docker access to all available RAM. I would be happy if somebody knew what the issue is and how to solve it.
[image: resources for docker (18 GB RAM)]

Here is a small subset of the Dockerfile that already reproduces the error:

```
FROM ros:humble-ros-base-jammy AS base

RUN apt update -qq
RUN apt install apt-utils software-properties-common openssh-client git-lfs -yqq
RUN add-apt-repository ppa:antiprism/ppa -y
RUN apt install apt-utils software-properties-common python3-pip g++ python3-dev python3-gdal libgdal-dev libsqlite3-mod-spatialite antiprism git libqt5gui5 libqt5core5a qtbase5-dev qtchooser qt5-qmake qtbase5-dev-tools libxtst6 libasound2 -yqq

# move requirements.txt to the container
COPY requirements.txt /tmp/requirements.txt

# install dependencies
RUN pip install --upgrade pip && pip install --no-cache-dir -r /tmp/requirements.txt
```

And here the requirements:

```
bitstring
black~=23.3
catkin_pkg
gps3
hacking
hypothesis>=6.41.0
j1939
mypy~=1.6.1
numpy>=1.21.2
opencv-python
pigpio
lgpio
python-can>=4.0.0
pylint~=2.13.8
pytest>=5.2
pyyaml
types-PyYAML
PyQt5>=5.15.4
PyQt5-stubs
PyQtWebEngine
pyqtlet
qt-material
RPi.GPIO
scipy
scikit-spatial
smbus
pandas-stubs
rich
ros2-easy-test

scikit-learn
ultralytics

# Requirements of ROS2
empy
lark
```

Comment: what is docker inspect returning?

Comment: @Milan can I run this if the docker container failed to build? The installation of `requirements.txt` is part of the build process.

Comment: what is your docker compose command?

Comment: run `docker ps -a` for container id

Comment: I do not use docker compose, I use `docker build --no-cache -t stda-ros-nodes . --ssh default=...` and this fails with the error in the question so there is no container I have an id for

Comment: Can you post a minimal Dockerfile and requirements.txt ?

Comment: @Philippe I added it to the question

Comment: I managed to build with this command : `docker build .` with only 4GB. Have you checked disk space usage ?

Comment: hm, disk space usage should be fine. What platform are you on, I am on arm64?

Comment: On a Windowa machine I also have no problem building it, but on Mac... The error message from the question indicates there is an problem installing PyQt, is there a problem with this?