# Does it need NVIDIA GPU for tensorflow/tensorflow Docker image?

Tags: docker, tensorflow

I run building tensorflow/tensorflow which is the CPU version of Docker image from Docker Hub. It builds on my computer which has no NVIDIA GPU. It throws some errors when using tensorflow libarary in python.

```
2020-06-13 07:47:05.279642: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:55] Could not load dynamic library 'libcuda.so.1'; dlerror: libcuda.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
2020-06-13 07:47:05.282730: E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_driver.cc:313] failed call to cuInit: UNKNOWN ERROR (303)
2020-06-13 07:47:05.287002: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_diagnostics.cc:156] kernel driver does not appear to be running on this host (f7be0d154c64): /proc/driver/nvidia/version does not exist
2020-06-13 07:47:05.297515: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:143] Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: AVX2 FMA
2020-06-13 07:47:05.566521: I tensorflow/core/platform/profile_utils/cpu_utils.cc:102] CPU Frequency: 2399995000 Hz
2020-06-13 07:47:05.571228: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:168] XLA service 0x7f3080000b20 initialized for platform Host (this does not guarantee that XLA will be used). Devices:
2020-06-13 07:47:05.571293: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:176]   StreamExecutor device (0): Host, Default Version
2020-06-13 07:47:10.799206: W tensorflow/core/framework/cpu_allocator_impl.cc:81] Allocation of 614400000 exceeds 10% of free system memory.
Killed
```

I want to know whether it need NVIDIA GPU for tensorflow/tensorflow Docker image with CPU version as well?
Please help me to build the Docker image with tensorflow CPU.

Answer (score 0):

These steps are working fine:

1. `docker run -it -d --name tensor tensorflow/tensorflow`
2. Move inside newly created container `docker exec -it tensor bash`
3. `python`
4. `>> import tensorflow`

Comment: I want to create a new docker image based on tensorflow/tensorflow. Not running 
just the tensorflow/tensorflow image. 
Please have a look into this, 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62351943/could-not-load-dynamic-library-libcuda-so-1-dlerror-libcuda-so-1-cannot-ope