# springboot native-image NoSuchMethodException: ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.<init>()

Tags: java, spring-boot, graalvm, graalvm-native-image

I'm tryying to use GraalVM native-image to compile a spring-boot project to build an .exe file.

my pom.xml :

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.4</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.qunhe.instdeco.diy</groupId>
    <artifactId>saas</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>saas</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
    </properties>

    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-milestone</id>
            <name>Spring milestone</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
                    <artifactId>tomcat-embed-websocket</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.experimental</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-native</artifactId>
            <version>0.10.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context-indexer</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.graalvm.nativeimage</groupId>
                <artifactId>native-image-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>21.2.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>com.qunhe.instdeco.diy.saas.SaasApplication</mainClass>
                    <buildArgs>
                        -Dspring.graal.remove-unused-autoconfig=true
                        --no-fallback
                        --initialize-at-build-time=org.springframework.util.unit.DataSize
                        --initialize-at-build-time=org.slf4j.MDC
                        --initialize-at-build-time=ch.qos.logback.classic.Level
                        --initialize-at-build-time=ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger
                        --initialize-at-build-time=ch.qos.logback.core.util.StatusPrinter
                        --initialize-at-build-time=ch.qos.logback.core.status.StatusBase
                        --initialize-at-build-time=ch.qos.logback.core.status.InfoStatus
                        --initialize-at-build-time=ch.qos.logback.core.spi.AppenderAttachableImpl
                        --initialize-at-build-time=org.slf4j.LoggerFactory
                        --initialize-at-build-time=ch.qos.logback.core.util.Loader
                        --initialize-at-build-time=org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder
                        --initialize-at-build-time=ch.qos.logback.classic.spi.ThrowableProxy
                        --initialize-at-build-time=ch.qos.logback.core.CoreConstants
                        --report-unsupported-elements-at-runtime
                        --allow-incomplete-classpath
                        -H:+ReportExceptionStackTraces
                    </buildArgs>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>native-image</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

warning occured in building :

```
The bundle named: org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.res.LocalStrings, has not been found. If the bundle is part of a module, verify the bundle name is a fully qualified class name. Otherwise verify the bundle path is accessible in the classpath.
```

built success , but when I run the .exe file :

```
  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::                (v2.5.4)

Aug 24, 2021 4:47:59 PM org.springframework.boot.StartupInfoLogger logStarting
INFO: Starting application using Java 11.0.12 on DESKTOP-9DBPFRN with PID 5872 (started by yuanque in D:\saas\target)
Aug 24, 2021 4:47:59 PM org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication logStartupProfileInfo
INFO: No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
Aug 24, 2021 4:47:59 PM org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext refresh
WARNING: Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor': Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor]: No default constructor found; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.<init>()
Aug 24, 2021 4:47:59 PM org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication reportFailure
SEVERE: Application run failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor': Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor]: No default constructor found; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.<init>()
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1316)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1214)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:564)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:524)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:213)
        at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:106)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:746)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:564)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:754)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:434)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:338)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1343)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1332)
        at com.qunhe.instdeco.diy.saas.SaasApplication.main(SaasApplication.java:15)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor]: No default constructor found; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.<init>()
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:83)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1308)
        ... 16 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.<init>()
        at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(DynamicHub.java:3349)
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructor(DynamicHub.java:2553)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:78)
        ... 17 more
```

It looks like the class disappeared during compilation...

Is this error related to the above warning ?

I have no idea what should i do ...

could someone help me ? :((

Comment: Did you find a solution to this problem? because I have the same issue

Comment: I'm also seeing this issue and the answers so far are not proving helpful. Did you happen to come across a solution?

Answer (score 0):

There is no AOT plugin in your pom

[plugin aot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ek2Uu.png)

[plugin aot2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BVOAJ.png)

Try use spring initializr site to create your project

Answer (score -1):

I faced the same problem for days and didn't find any answer.
Finally, after some help from graalvm community, I found the solution.

If you are using Mac or Windows, then the problem is memory configuration issue, see https://docs.spring.io/spring-native/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#_out_of_memory_error_when_building_the_native_image.

Follow this answer on StackOverflow [How to assign more memory to docker container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44533319/how-to-assign-more-memory-to-docker-container/44533437#44533437)