# OOM when building quarkus native application

Tags: docker, quarkus, graalvm, graalvm-native-image

Not sure what am I missing? After reading multiple blogs and StackOverflow questions, I tried increasing the memory to Xmx12G but with no success. I keep getting msg to increase memory.
Has anyone faced the issue in the recent past and is it been solved?
This is just the plain application downloaded directly from the quarkus website.

```
docker run --env LANG=C --rm -v qaurkus-test/target/qaurkus-test-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT-native-image-source-jar:/project:z --name build-native-bkbGA quay.io/quarkus/ubi-quarkus-native-image:21.2-java11 -J-Djava.util.logging.manager=org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager -J-Dsun.nio.ch.maxUpdateArraySize=100 -J-Dvertx.logger-delegate-factory-class-name=io.quarkus.vertx.core.runtime.VertxLogDelegateFactory -J-Dvertx.disableDnsResolver=true -J-Dio.netty.leakDetection.level=DISABLED -J-Dio.netty.allocator.maxOrder=3 -J-Duser.language=en -J-Duser.country=US -J-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -H:InitialCollectionPolicy=com.oracle.svm.core.genscavenge.CollectionPolicy\$BySpaceAndTime -H:+JNI -H:+AllowFoldMethods -jar qaurkus-test-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT-runner.jar -H:FallbackThreshold=0 -H:+ReportExceptionStackTraces -J-Xmx12G -H:-AddAllCharsets -H:EnableURLProtocols=http -H:-UseServiceLoaderFeature -H:+StackTrace -H:-ParseOnce qaurkus-test-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT-runner
[qaurkus-test-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT-runner:25]    classlist:   6,968.00 ms,  0.94 GB
[qaurkus-test-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT-runner:25]        (cap):     534.58 ms,  0.94 GB
[qaurkus-test-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT-runner:25]        setup:   2,329.28 ms,  0.94 GB
The bundle named: messages, has not been found. If the bundle is part of a module, verify the bundle name is a fully qualified class name. Otherwise verify the bundle path is accessible in the classpath.
19:29:29,666 INFO  [org.jbo.threads] JBoss Threads version 3.4.2.Final
Error: Image build request failed with exit status 137
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  43.324 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2021-09-01T00:59:39+05:30
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal io.quarkus.platform:quarkus-maven-plugin:2.2.1.Final:build (default) on project qaurkus-test: Failed to build quarkus application: io.quarkus.builder.BuildException: Build failure: Build failed due to errors
[ERROR]     [error]: Build step io.quarkus.deployment.pkg.steps.NativeImageBuildStep#build threw an exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to build native image
[ERROR]     at io.quarkus.deployment.pkg.steps.NativeImageBuildStep.build(NativeImageBuildStep.java:235)
[ERROR]     at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
[ERROR]     at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
[ERROR]     at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
[ERROR]     at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
[ERROR]     at io.quarkus.deployment.ExtensionLoader$2.execute(ExtensionLoader.java:820)
[ERROR]     at io.quarkus.builder.BuildContext.run(BuildContext.java:277)
[ERROR]     at org.jboss.threads.ContextHandler$1.runWith(ContextHandler.java:18)
[ERROR]     at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$Task.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:2449)
[ERROR]     at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1478)
[ERROR]     at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
[ERROR]     at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:501)
[ERROR] Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Image generation failed. Exit code was 137 which indicates an out of memory error. Consider increasing the Xmx value for native image generation by setting the "quarkus.native.native-image-xmx" property
[ERROR]     at io.quarkus.deployment.pkg.steps.NativeImageBuildStep.imageGenerationFailed(NativeImageBuildStep.java:372)
[ERROR]     at io.quarkus.deployment.pkg.steps.NativeImageBuildStep.build(NativeImageBuildStep.java:205)
[ERROR]     ... 11 more
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally, got it working.

1. check how much memory docker is allocated using `docker stats` command
2. Follow the process mentioned in the [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44533319/how-to-assign-more-memory-to-docker-container) and increase it to atleast 8G, in my case max memory consumed was around 7G