# Container 'docker' exceeded memory limit

Tags: sonarqube, bitbucket, pipeline

Hi I have the following pipeline config

```
image: maven:3.3.9

definitions:
  steps:
    - step: &build-step
        name: SonarQube analysis
        script:
          - pipe: sonarsource/sonarcloud-scan:1.4.0
            variables:
              SONAR_HOST_URL: ${SONAR_HOST_URL} # Get the value from the repository/workspace variable.
              SONAR_SCANNER_OPTS: -Xmx1024m
              SONAR_TOKEN: ${SONAR_TOKEN} # Get the value from the repository/workspace variable. You shouldn't set secret in clear text here.
  caches:
    sonar: ~/.sonar

clone:
  depth: full

pipelines:
  branches:
    '{master}': # or the name of your main branch
      - step: *build-step
```

I want to increase the size of the docker to 2x could you please help with the proper YML config for the same?

I tried changing it to

```
      - step:
          size: 2x
```

but it won't work, I get erros that step is null or missing

Comment: according to [this](https://phoenixnap.com/kb/docker-memory-and-cpu-limit) by default docker uses all your memory. So I assume somehow somewhere there is a memory limit, maybe when docker is run. Doesn't look like you can change it from within the yaml file.

Comment: this could also help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44533319/how-to-assign-more-memory-to-docker-container

Comment: according to [this](https://www.baeldung.com/ops/docker-memory-limit) it might be possible, you can try some of those suggestions (for the record I just searched "docker increase memory limit" and "docker increase memory limit in yaml file")

Comment: thank you @Matthias let me try those