# Error while bal native build for docker using Ballerina

Tags: ballerina

I'm trying to build a ballerina application using the GraalVM native image compiler by following this doc (https://ballerina.io/learn/build-a-native-executable) and getting the following error during the docker image build phase.

Error:

```
> [build 4/4] RUN sh build-native.sh my_service.jar my_service:
#0 3.676 WARNING: Unknown module: org.graalvm.nativeimage.llvm specified to --add-exports
#0 3.678 WARNING: Unknown module: org.graalvm.nativeimage.llvm specified to --add-exports
#0 3.680 WARNING: Unknown module: org.graalvm.nativeimage.llvm specified to --add-exports
#0 59.74 ========================================================================================================================
#0 59.74 GraalVM Native Image: Generating 'my_service' (executable)...
#0 59.76 ========================================================================================================================
#0 75.84 Error: Image build request failed with exit status 137
------
ERROR: failed to solve: executor failed running [/bin/sh -c sh build-native.sh my_service.jar my_service]: exit code: 137
error [k8s plugin]: module [wso2/my_service:0.1.0] docker build failed. refer to the build log
        warning: Detected conflicting jar files:
                'ballerina-rt-2201.4.0.jar' dependency of 'wso2/my_service' conflict with 'opentelemetry-api-1.0.0.jar' dependency of 'ballerinax/jaeger'
```

Env info:

JDK : 11.0.18 (arm64) "Eclipse Adoptium" - "OpenJDK 11.0.18"

GraalVM : graalvm-ce-java11-darwin-aarch64-22.3.1

Answer (score 1):

Exit code 137 suggests an out of memory issue. [Increasing the memory allocated to docker fixes the issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44533319/how-to-assign-more-memory-to-docker-container/44533437#44533437).
Since GraalVM build consumes significant amount of memory, it is advisable to have atleast 8GB allocated to docker. (Refer to the prerequisites for docker build)