# How to give more memory for Generic container ? [TestContainers]

Tags: docker, memory, docker-compose, memory-management, testcontainers

I have a test, which uses `testContainers` technology to run docker container:

```
GenericContainer(MY_SAMBA_IMAGE)               
                .withEnv("...")
                .withEnv("...")
                .withEnv("...")
                .withPrivilegedMode(true)
                .waitingFor(...)
                .start()
```

But when I run it I see that it can't run because of memory error:

```
17:18:56.884 [docker-java-stream--1885712736] INFO SAMBA_CONTAINER -- STDERR: ERROR(<class 'MemoryError'>): uncaught exception - 
17:18:56.884 [docker-java-stream--1885712736] INFO SAMBA_CONTAINER -- STDERR:   File "/app/inno-samba/lib/python3.7/site-packages/samba/netcmd/__init__.py", line 285, in _run
17:18:56.885 [docker-java-stream--1885712736] INFO SAMBA_CONTAINER -- STDERR:     return self.run(*args, **kwargs)
17:18:56.885 [docker-java-stream--1885712736] INFO SAMBA_CONTAINER -- STDERR:   File "/app/inno-samba/lib/python3.7/site-packages/samba/netcmd/domain/provision.py", line 362, in run
17:18:56.885 [docker-java-stream--1885712736] INFO SAMBA_CONTAINER -- STDERR:     backend_store_size=backend_store_size)
17:18:56.885 [docker-java-stream--1885712736] INFO SAMBA_CONTAINER -- STDERR:   File "/app/inno-samba/lib/python3.7/site-packages/samba/provision/__init__.py", line 2307, in provision
17:18:56.885 [docker-java-stream--1885712736] INFO SAMBA_CONTAINER -- STDERR:     schemadn=names.schemadn, base_schema=base_schema)
17:18:56.885 [docker-java-stream--1885712736] INFO SAMBA_CONTAINER -- STDERR:   File "/app/inno-samba/lib/python3.7/site-packages/samba/schema.py", line 114, in __init__
17:18:56.886 [docker-java-stream--1885712736] INFO SAMBA_CONTAINER -- STDERR:     self.ldb = SamDB(global_schema=False, am_rodc=False)
```

When I run the same container using **docker-compose** file - everything is ok.

Does testcontainers additionally limit the memory ? is there way to give more memory for that container ?

Comment: docker itself sets memory constraints for the container. and see more https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44533319/how-to-assign-more-memory-to-docker-container

Comment: @Tanveer well, I know it. But (as I mentioned in the topic) the same container created from the same image is successfully running  using docker-compose on the SAME maschine.